# @Cacheable "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration"

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning Spring and Data JPA. I have a problem with Ehcache. I want to cache the return value of one of my methods that returns some records from database. This is an exercise with Ehcache instance pre-configured (I assume). The problem is that I cannot use the annotation @Cacheable to mark my method as the method that its return value should be cached. I get an incompatible type compile error (required: boolean, found: String). Here is one of the classes in my service layer that I think I should put @Cacheable here (am I right?):

```
package wad.datatables.service;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import wad.datatables.domain.Book;
import wad.datatables.repository.BookRepository;
import wad.datatables.view.DataTablesResponse;

@Service
public class JpaDataTablesBookService implements DataTablesBookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;    

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true) 
    @Cacheable("books")
    public DataTablesResponse getBooks(String queryString) {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "title");

        Page<Book> page = bookRepository.findByTitleContaining(queryString, pageable);

        DataTablesResponse response = new DataTablesResponse();
        response.setTotalRecords(page.getTotalElements());
        response.setTotalDisplayRecords(page.getNumberOfElements());
        response.setData(page.getContent());

        return response;
    }
}
```

And my repository layer (only one class):

```
package wad.datatables.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import wad.datatables.domain.Book;

public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {        
    Page<Book> findByTitleContaining(String title, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And here are my config files:

cache.xml (located in WEB-INF/spring/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And ehcache.xml (located in src/main/resources):

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
         updateCheck="true" 
         monitoring="autodetect" 
         dynamicConfig="true">
    <cache name="books" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" eternal="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because you are using wrong Cacheable annotation. Instead of `javax.persistence.Cacheable` use `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was disappointed about getting an answer. Because of inappropriate time for asking (it was midnight here in Europe), my question went down in unanswered questions without even being seen, and I couldn't ask it again, because it would be marked as a duplicate question! Thank you again. But wouldn't it better if Spring would have used another annotation that wasn't identical to java's original annotation's name? I used auto-import feature of Netbeans, and didn't know that there's another annotation with the same name.

Comment: It's hard to define class (annotation) with unique name across whole Java ecosystem if the name has to be meaningful. That's is why Java class is identified by the full class name (package name + class name). Regarding your code, does it compile? According to JEE [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html) the `javax.persistence.Cacheable` cannot be applied to methods.